# JQuery disable tab 3 when click tab 2?

Tags: jquery-ui

I am new to this forum so first let me say a big hello and thanks for providing such a great website!

I am new to JQuery but I love it, I have some JQuery tabs doing the usual List/Edit/Create stuff in a backend.

I have managed to set the edit tab to deisabled when viewing the list tab (as you need to slect a list item to edit) and it is enabled when a list item edit icon is clicked.

The question I have is if I then click the third tab how do I disable the second tab onlick?

This is my standard tab code...

```
$(function() 
        {
        $("#tabs").tabs({disabled: [2]});

        $("#tabs").tabs();      
        }
    );
```

HTML:

```
<div class="demo">

<div id="tabs">
    <ul>
        <li><wont let me post 3 links>Jobs</a></li>
        <li><a href="#tabs-2">Create Job</a></li>
        <li><a href="#tabs-3">Edit Job</a></li>
    </ul>
    <div id="tabs-1" style="background-color: #fff">

        Include...

    </div>
    <div id="tabs-2" style="background-color: #fff">

        Include...

    </div>
    <div id="tabs-3" style="background-color: #fff">

        Include...

    </div>
</div>
```

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

First you HTML is no correct so the plugin does not initialiaze well. The first tab button link is incorrect:

```
<li><wont let me post 3 links>Jobs</a></li>
```

Should be

```
<li><a href="#tabs-1">Jobs</a></li>
```

Then you are initializing two times the plugin, only do it once.
In the `show` event handler, enable/disable the tabs according to the actual tab shown:

```
$(function() 
{
    $("#tabs").tabs({
        //disabled: [2],
        show: function(event, ui) {
            if (ui.index === 0) {
                $('#tabs').tabs('enable', 1);
                $('#tabs').tabs('enable', 2);
            } else {
                $('#tabs').tabs('disable', ui.index === 1 ? 2 : ui.index === 2 ? 1 : -1);
            }
        }
    });

    /*$("#tabs").tabs();      
    }*/
);
```

Here is a live working example on [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/didierg/79T9d/)

Comment: Ha I typed that because stack overflow wouldn't let me type 3 links in - it normally says as you suggested :)

Comment: You're welcome. Tell me if it is what you were looking after and accept the answer if it does.